# Request.form not finding my fields even though they seem to exist

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to submit a form with Flask using dynamic field names for multiple check boxes within a form. The naming of the fields seems to work and they have the names I want, but when I try to use request.form.get() to get the information from the form using the dynamic field names it is just returning None, meaning that the dictionary that is returned does not contain the names of my fields. Here is my code:

**The Form And Example of name**

[image: ![Form]

[image: Example Name]

**HTML**

```
<form action="{{url_for('main.updatealleles', id=fish.id)}}" method="post">
    <div id="updateAllelesBlock">
        <table id="alleleTable" style="margin: auto; margin-top:20px;">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Unidentified</th>
                <th>Identified</th>
                <th>Heterozygous</th>
                <th>Homozygous</th>
                <th>Hemizygous</th>
            </tr>
            {%for allele in alleles%}
                <tr>
                    <th>{{allele.name}}</th>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name = {{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Unidentified"}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name = {{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Identified"}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name = {{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Heterozygous"}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name = {{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Homozygous"}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name = {{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Hemizygous"}}</td>
                </tr>
            {%endfor%}
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 10px;">Update</button>
</form>
```

**PYTHON**

```
@bp.route("/fish/<id>/updatealleles/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def updatealleles(id):
    fish = Fish.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()
    alleles = Allele.query.filter_by(fish=fish).all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        for allele in alleles:
            print(request.form.get(f"{allele.name.replace(' ', '')}Unidentfied"), file=sys.stderr)
            print(request.form.get(f"{allele.name.replace(' ', '')}Identfied"), file=sys.stderr)
            #THIS IS ALWAYS PRINTING NONE, SAME WITH ALL OTHER FIELDS

            #therefore these, and the other fields are being set to None rather than true/false
            allele.unidentified = request.form.get(f"{allele.name.replace(' ', '')}Unidentified")
            allele.identified = request.form.get(f"{allele.name.replace(' ', '')}Identified")

        db.session.commit()

            return redirect(url_for("main.updatealleles", id=fish.id))
    
        

    return render_template('updatealleles.html', fish=fish, alleles = alleles, title = "Update Alleles")
```

The reason I need the dynamic name fields is because there could be any number of different allele objects (they are SQLAlchemy objects) and the table is there to set different attributes for each allele object to true or false, shown in the python example.
If there is a completely different way to do this that I am no aware of then I am also happy to try that.

I know there have been some similar questions to this, but I have tried all of their suggestions and none of them have worked for me, so any help would be greatly appreciated and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You could try `print(request.form)` to see what is being received.

Comment: I tried that and it seems that the form is returning nothing (just and empty dict), so I guess the problem must be something to do with the form not submitting correctly

Comment: Okay, I have solved the problem of it returning an empty dict by replacing the form method woth "POST" rather than "post", but I am still having the same problem with the fields returning as None

Comment: This is what I now get when i print request.form after checking the two tickboxes for "unidentified" ```ImmutableMultiDict([('Allele1Unidentified  checked ></td>\r\n                    <td><input type=', 'on'), ('Allele2Unidentified  checked ></td>\r\n                    <td><input type=', 'on')])```, so I now think the problem is with the name that is being returned, it does not match the name shown in the form when inspected

Comment: You haven't closed the input tag in your template so some of the HTML is getting included as the name of the input. Just change `...+"Unidentified"}}</td>` to `...+"Unidentified"}}></td>` for all of your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have the solution. It turns out even though the names appeared to be working when inspected, the jinja2 string was actually returned as unclosed when the form was requested extra information was included in the name.
All I had to do to fix that was to add single quotation marks, either side of the id, so now it looks like this, for example:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name = '{{allele.name.replace(" ", "")+"Unidentified"}}'</td>
```

and then the python can work like this:

```
allele.unidentified= request.form.get(f"{allele.name.replace(' ', '')}Unidentified") == "on"
```

And the same for each other field.